# Zend Lucene search related fields?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I have a lot of paired fields (hoursDistance1, cityName1, hoursDistance2, cityName2, hoursDistance3, cityName3, etc.).

What query do I need to search for so that Lucene scores based on both fields having the correct terms instead of just one of them? i.e. if I search for a city 3 hours from here with this name, how do I get it to return results where hoursDistanceN is 3 hours from here AND cityNameN is this without scoring the other pairs of fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a document for each pair. So instead of

```
id | hours1 | name1 | hours2 | name2 | ...
```

You would have:

```
id | pair_num = 1 | hours | name
id | pair_num = 2 | hours | name
...
```

Since you only want to search one pair at a time, you shouldn't need to merge the results together or anything.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do this by denormalizing your data:
Create a Lucene document for each pair of fields,
e.g. if:

```
hoursDistance1=3,cityName1=London
```

Create a document with the fields:

```
hoursDistance=3,cityName=London,pairIndex=1
```

And then run a query like:

```
hoursDistance=5 AND cityName=Leeds
```

Comment: Creating documents for each set of pairs is not possible as they are part of a location document, with each pair of fields relative to the location.

Comment: I believe you need to explain this a little further. How did you create the fields? Maybe using a spatial search module is better.